# How to use Two-way data binding in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I need to **enable my Button** after check some condition, i want to call one method using **@InverseBinding OR Two Way data binding** and reflect the changes with return value.

my Code :

```
<Button 
      android:id="@+id/save_btn_disabled_3"
      android:enabled="@={controller}"
      ....
      />
```

my Two Way data binding logic here :

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "enable")
    fun getEnableButton(view:View, controller:Controller): Boolean {
    //some conditions
        return false
    }
```

i want to know am i going in correct direction ?, code is ok ? 
please suggest me.

Comment: two-way data binding use for the attributes available in given link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes.Be careful not to introduce infinite loops when using two-way data binding.

Comment: First you check the condition if it is correct then you will `enable` the `button` and it `onclick` method is that it you want?

Answer (score 2):

First Add Button Status Object

```
<variable
            name="button"
            type="com.brl.test.app.vm.ButtonStatus" />

<Button 
      android:id="@+id/save_btn_disabled_3"
      bind:state_change="@{button.state}"
      ....
      />
```

Set your logic in buttonEnabled funtion then Enable Your Button

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:state_change"})
  public static void buttonEnabled(TextView view, State state) {
     
    view.setEnabled(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set one variable in  field like:

```
<variable
    name="wantsToVisibleProgress"
    type="boolean" />
```

and set it in your button like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/constraint_select_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_blue_big"
    android:enabled="@={wantsToVisibleProgress}"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="@{v -> fragment.onClick()}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_evse_one">
```

You can set that value like this:

```
binding.setWantsToVisibleProgress(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to call a function, not dependent any variable.